# How to find server side include's own filename?

Tags: apache, include, ssi

This is an unusual request, I know, but I have an include that uses <!--#flastmod file="this_filename.shtml" --> in it (because LAST_MODIFIED will only return the modification date of the calling document) and if I was able to use an envariable for 'file', I wouldn't have to worry about the code breaking if the include's name were to change.

The SSI variables I tested all return the path and filename of the calling document, not the include itself. Are there any that will return the include's information?

Using Apache 2.0 on RHEL here. NOT using PHP, just straight SSI code in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Use the echo command and the `document_uri` SSI environment variable to do this:

```
<!--#echo var="document_uri"-->
```

**References**

- [CGI Programming on the World Wide Web, Chapter 5: Server Side Includes - Additional SSI Environment Variables](http://www.oreilly.com/openbook/cgi/ch05_03.html#CGI-CHP-5-TBL-2)